# BQ query, not exists/joins

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

in a BigQuery I have a table.

| VM | Package |
| --- | --- |
| VM1 | A |
| VM2 | B |
| VM3 | A |
| VM4 | B |
| VM1 | B |
| VM2 | C |
| VM3 | B |
| VM4 | C |

How can I get results, so all distinct VMs would be listed, but having `Package` column with value `null` (or empty, or `Yes` and `No`) if particular package not exists. I.e. I need to be listed all VMs (without duplicating), which have the package `A` installed, and the rest with value let say `null`:

| VM | Package |
| --- | --- |
| VM1 | A |
| VM2 | null |
| VM3 | A |
| VM4 | null |

Comment: Can you show the query you have tried?

Comment: I tried many different, but always get wrong results. Tried to get one table with result `Package = A`, then get second table without Package A, and join them, but did not manage to get the second table. I.e. for second one:

```
SELECT distinct VM FROM `xxx.myTbl`
WHERE NOT Package LIKE 'A'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check COUNT of package A for each VM and apply condition on the COUNT

```
SELECT VM, IF(COUNTIF(Package = 'A') = 0, NULL, 'A') AS Package
FROM table1
GROUP BY VM
```

Comment: this awesome, works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
select VM, 
  if('A' in unnest(array_agg(Package)), 'A', null) Package
from your_table
group by VM
```

with output

[image]